# JavaScript не получается вывести значения в браузере, скажите пожалуйста почему

Tags: javascript

[image: вот что неправильно?]

ну так вот написано для 30 символов

Comment: Потому что у вас куча синтаксических ошибок.

Comment: Откуда вы только берете такие синтаксисы. И кто вас только учит так программировать.

Comment: Вы просто не читаете книг и документации.

Comment: Я считаю, что такие вопросы, нужно удалять без разбирательств, они не несут никакой пользы ресурсу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В `HTML5` `type="text/javascript"` можно опустить, он не
   обязателен.
2. Перестаньте тыкать фигурные скобки и точки с запятой куда попало. Вы в данный момент не понимаете, что для чего нужно.

Поэтому у вас два варианта:

1. Если вы хотите заняться программированием, то почитать книжек и документацию ([Клик](https://learn.javascript.ru)).
2. Если вас заставили это делать в учебном заведении, но вы не хотите этого делать, то взять рабочий пример.

Рабочий пример:

```
<script>
x=4;
y=5;
if(x > y)
  document.write("x > y");
else
  document.write("x < y");
</script>
```

Comment: `document.write` - зло!

Comment: @And пример создан для пункта №2, по примеру автора. Т.е. сугубо для обучения. Я с вами согласен, метод бесполезный.